# my contract was recently renewed, but I was hoping for permanent job

Tags: professionalism

My contract was recently renewed to the end of the year.  I was hoping for permanent job. My boss had mentioned a while back that she will discuss hiring me with the corporate office, but have not heard anything back and I didn't follow up with her.

can I discuss this with my boss before signing the contract with agency. if yes, what should I say.

Comment: Your boss mentioned this before, so she's clearly open to the idea - why do you think following up with her might be a problem?

Answer (score 3):

> can I discuss this with my boss before signing the contract with
>   agency. if yes, what should I say.

Certainly you can.

You can remind her that she mentioned hiring you a while back and that you hadn't heard any update. You could ask if there is any update. And of course you can remind her that you'd really like to be hired as a permanent employee.

It won't hurt to ask.

And based on her answer you can decide if you should be looking for a new job while you finish up your extended contract through the end of the year, or if there is a real possibility that this will turn into a permanent job.

Comment: These contracts are not a promise to stay for some definite term, they are basically just an agreement on the rate of pay until either party decides to terminate. The OP is free to depart as soon as he gets a more favorable offer.

Comment: True, but such contracts are rare. If the employer is not guaranteeing payment for the duration, then the employee has no obligation to remain.